# Crontab Absolute Path Auto Fill In

Tags: shell, cron

Hi there I have a shell command that I need to put into crontab to run periodically.

I have test my script in the working directory, say my home directory, and it works fine. Something similar like:

```
python myscript.py <input >/tmp/output
```

As you can see the myscript.py and input file are located in my home directory and the output should go into the tmp folder.

I know I could use 'which' command to get the path of python and 'pwd' command to get the working directory while I am done with my test. However, I am wondering is there a tool or command to translate that into the complete version easily. 
How could I easily replace every thing with the full path so I could put that 'full path version' into crontab and it could be recognized globally.

```
python myscript.py <input >/tmp/output
... magic ...
/usr/bin/python /home/myAccount/myscript.py </home/myAccount/input >/tmp/output
```

Answer (score 1):

For bash you could do that easily with one command:

```
echo "$(type -P python) $HOME/myscript.py <$HOME/input >/tmp/output"
```

And that doesn't rely on external command like `which` or `pwd`. You can also place that on a script. Just add `#!/bin/bash` on the header.